# query_posts() doesn't seem to be called in my page

Tags: wp-query, loop, query-posts

I've a problem with my `query_posts()` call.

Here is my code:

```
$results = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT post_id FROM " . $wpdb->postmeta . " WHERE meta_key = 'mashsb_shares' ORDER BY CAST(meta_value AS SIGNED) DESC LIMIT 0, 20");

$top_ideas = array();

foreach($results as $result) {
    foreach($result as $key => $value) {
        array_push($top_ideas, $value);
    }
}
print_r($top_ideas);

query_posts( array( 'post__in' => $top_ideas, 'orderby' => 'post__in' ) );
```

My problem is that posts doesn't appear in the order of my `post__in` array (`$top_ideas`).

[image: Here is the result]

My `print_r()` shows the right array, so my `$results`'s query works good. The problem is in my `query_posts()` call, but I can't find what problem is... I just understood that the query_posts() method is never called. If I take it out, nothing change.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You should not be using `query_posts()` here.  http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/50761/when-to-use-wp-query-query-posts-and-pre-get-posts  and   https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/query_posts/

Answer (score 0):

You may need to add this to your `query_posts()` call `'order' => 'ASC'` so it should look like this:

```
query_posts( array(
    'post__in' => $top_ideas,
    'orderby' => 'post__in',
    'order' => 'ASC'
) );
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Nothing changed. My query_posts() doesn't seem call...

Comment: Just to make sure, are you running your code through the while loop? '<?php
query_posts( array( 'post__in' => $top_ideas, 'orderby' => 'post__in', 'order' => 'ASC' ) );
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
 echo '<li>';
 the_title();
 echo '</li>';
endwhile;

?>'

Comment: Your code displays ids in the wrong order, but it is better than my code: 37, 34, 42, 58. This is very strange...

Comment: My loop is just after my query_posts(), like yours.

Comment: You may want to try and use `WP_Query` instead for your query. Find documentation on this link here https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/WP_Query. This will help alleviate any issues with your query or any other queries encroaching on the data.